# Detect if the connection is secure or not

Tags: android, ssl-certificate

I want to detect whether the network traffic is monitored with Fiddler or proxies like Fiddler. If so I don't want my app to proceed further. 
To achieve this I am doing following things :

1. Create A keystore :

   ```
   private KeyStore getKeyStore() {
       KeyStore keyStore = null;
       try {
           // Load CAs from an InputStream
           // (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
           CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

           InputStream caInput = getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                   "/assets/mycert");

           Certificate ca;
           try {
               ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
               System.out.println("ca="
                       + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());

           } finally {
               caInput.close();
           }

           // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
           String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
           keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
           keyStore.load(null, null);
           keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

       } catch (CertificateException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return keyStore;
   }
   ```
2. Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore

   ```
   String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
   TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
   tmf.init(keyStore);
   ```
3. Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager

   ```
   SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
   context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
   ```
4. set SSLSocketFactory for out connection

   ```
   connection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
   ```

This always makes the connection successful. I don't know whether this is the right way to achieve what I want.

Or is there any other right way to do so?

Thanks in advance.